# Oracle SQL Developer instance viewer report

Tags: sql, oracle, instance, oracle-sqldeveloper

In my company we take a screenshot of the Oracle SQLDeveloper instance viewer report for health check purpose on some databases everyday.

To spend less time on this activity (because I have to take a screenshot of multiple databases), I want to schedule this report in an automatic mode (maybe in one HTML or something similar to be easily readable).

Do you know if there is a way to obtain such a screen automatically?

If you know a free tool to schedule and obtain a report like it please let me know too :)

Comment: It's a series of reports all on a single screen. You can find the queries we're using in the View > Log > Statements panel. You can then take those queries and build reports that could be ran on demand via many different solutions, including Oracle APEX, which is also free. I like that you're using the tool, but taking screenshots of it and mailing it around the company is far from ideal. It sounds like you need to stand up something like Oracle Enterprise Manager, em12c